# suspicious logins root

Tags: ssh, cron

i have noticed suspicious logins with root account on my server so i created new admin account and assigned root permissions to this account and disabled the root account. had a look at the /var/log/auth.log file and can see there are no more logins from the suspicious ip anymore but it is showing:

```
Oct 25 06:06:01 SERVERHOSTNAME CRON[10452]: pam_unix(cron:session):   session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Oct 25 06:06:01 SERVERHOSTNAME CRON[10452]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
```

are these scheduled cron jobs? can these be ignored?

Comment: I have another question, say if I want to block a certain ip do i just enter the following for iptables to block it?

`# iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport ssh -s ~ip address~ -j DROP`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The session entry is due to some `cron` job running as `root`. It is being spawned at 06:06.

Check relevant `cron` entries for `root` and find out what is being run at that time exactly.

Possible places to look at:

- `/etc/crontab`
- `/etc/cron.d/*`
- `/etc/cron.hourly/*`
- Root's `crontab`: `crontab -e` as `root`

If `anacron` is not active:

- `/etc/cron.daily/*`
- `/etc/cron.weekly/*`
- `/etc/cron.monthly/*`

---

Just to add, if your system was compromised before, stop using it, take a backup (if needed), setup the OS again. Later you can analyze the backed up contents to dig further regarding the intrusion.

Comment: i dont see any successful logins, all looks good, was just concerned.

Comment: nope still can't see it, will wait for moderator to remove it.

i had a lookat at /etc/crontab, please see contents below (hope it works this time with the formatting)

`22 * * * * root cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly`
`17 0 * * * root test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/$`
`20 4 * * 7 root test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/$`
`35 3 20 * * root test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc$`